# Redux Store subscribe not firing

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to get a piece of data from the store once the app loads to load in the correct components.

I'm using the following code in `App.js`:

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
    const [verified, setVerified] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        alert('useEffect fired');
        store.subscribe(() => {
            alert('Subscribe fired: ' + store.getState().userReducer.phoneVerified);
            setVerified(store.getState().userReducer.phoneVerified);
        });
    }, []);
};
```

The `alert()` "useEffect fired" fires in the simulator (iPhone X) as well as on the actual device.

The second `alert()` "Subscribe fired" fires correctly in the simulator but does not fire on the actual device.

My `store.js`:

```
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    whitelist: [
        'userReducer',
    ]
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
);

const persistor = persistStore(store);

export {
    store,
    persistor,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Redux has some issues when storing it on my devices. I've solved it by removing Redux completely and using AsyncStorage directly instead.